# Cloudkit Production Records Disappeared

Tags: cloudkit

An entire table of Cloudkit records just disappeared from my public production database. The other table of records was intact. I didn't do anything to delete these records. I looked at the logs and I couldn't see anything that looked out of the ordinary. I have no idea how this could have possibly happened. Is CloudKit so unstable that this can just happen randomly? Can anyone give me some insight on this - how can I go about tracking down the source of this issue? Should I assume this is a CloudKit issue? Is there a way to tell what actually happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per one of my dev friends on Twitter, it's a known issue regarding indexes (not data), and Apple's working on it. No ETA I'm aware of, as of 11PM CST.

My app has 8 tables and 3 of them are 'missing' record data.

Comment: I really hope they fix it (and soon). Otherwise, a crucial table disappeared from my public DB too.

Comment: The twitter friend I referenced above can see all of his records again, so it's apparently some kind of rolling update. I still have 3 tables affected, I'll update my comment when that changes.

Comment: My records appeared again, earlier this evening. Intact. No modifications to timestamps or anything.

Comment: Yes, all is back.